# Need to understand how to setup a map reduce type function to import 50K contacts from a CSV file using AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, aws-lambda, amazon-emr

I have a requirement to import 50K(this number changes) records in our database applying business logics to each record (or a bulk of records), I plan to implement it by breaking the recordset into multiple chunks of 500 records and sending messages to hornetq queue where a MDB processes the chunk of records. This solution helps me to spread the process in multiple processes by having a MDB pool of 30 threads and also since i use persistent queues my messages are persisted and hence in case of fault the entire process is not affected. Firstly, i would love to know if this is an ideal approach and secondly since we are completely in AWS, are there solutions(or combination of) in AWS which are designed to handle these kind of applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are so specific to Map Reduce, go ahead and utilize AWS Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) to perform your Map Reduce activity with your custom processing and source being stored in S3 or pulled from any other source.

You have to manage the infrastructure, it is not a managed service

Alternatively, you can use AWS Glue ETL jobs to perform the same using Spark. This is a managed ETL service which gets you with pre-generated spark template to begin with.

To choose between Glue vs EMR, read more about Spark vs Map Reduce and decide yourself.

Hope this helps!!